Second Opinion on Superheterodyne Receiver Design
I've design a superheterodyne receiver for frequencies between 88-108MHz. Below shows the final schematic and I wanted to get a second opinion on it. Specifically, I wanted to know if the general layout is good and if it would work. Obviously, I don't expect it to work since it's a complicated design and it's the first revision, I just don't want to make any stupid (obvious) mistakes.
Component Values that are Hard to See :

C7 : 28pF
L6 : 19nH
L7 : 19nH
C8 : 1nF
C11 : 1nF
L8 : 80nH
C12 : 10pF
C13 : 1nF
C14 : 1uF

Schematic :

Simulation of Section 1 :

AC analysis from 10-200MHz.
98.1MHz in band signal (100uVpp) + 98.3MHz interfering             signal (1mVpp)



Simulation of Section 3 :

AC analysis from 1-50MHz.
Vout when Vin is at 10.7MHz 100uVpp
Vout when Vin is at 10.7MHz 10mVpp
Vout when Vin is at 10.7MHz 1Vpp






Sorry if I did not say it, but yes, I have simulated the circuit. I've simulated sections 1 and 3 with a 50 ohm source and load and it looks good. I didn't do sections 2 and 4 since I didn't find any simulation models for the ICs, so they're all based on calculations.

Please add spectral results of a sweep across a particular channel to see how it responds spectrally. Please also add similar results for a channel with a low amplitude in band signal and a large amplitude interfering signal one channel distant.

I edited the question and added simulation results. My only concern is that the input to section 3 (coming from the LT5560 mixer) is at a high voltage which the amplifier does not anticipate (one simulation shows the amplifier with high input voltage, which there is much lower gain). Is this a problem?
