Boost Converter Output Isn't Desired Value
I used the MIC2619 switching regulator for a boost converter application which takes +5V and outputs +12V. After assembling the circuit, the output voltage is only +4.8V. The schematic of the circuit I'm trying to power with it is in my previous question "Second Opinion on Superheterodyne Receiver Design", in short I require around 150-200mA of current. Is the output low because the load draws too much current? Would the MIC2288 be a good replacement?
MIC2619 Datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic2619.pdf
MIC2288 Datasheet : https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC2288-Data-Sheet-DS20006034C.pdf
Schematic:


+4.8 V out with 5 V in sounds like for some reason the chip isn't switching at all and you're just getting voltage passing directly through L11 and D2. I'd be looking for physical defects like the EN pin connection being broken or R18 or R19 being broken/disconnected.

Also check if the IC is mounted in the correct orientation.

I checked on my scope and the SW pin is just a constant +5V, and I assume the +4.8V is just voltage drop across D2. I think it's in the right orientation, assuming the dot on the package is the pin 1 indicator. Do you suggest I replace it with another one (can it output 150mA)?

Ref: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/715166/second-opinion-on-superheterodyne-receiver-design I don't see where you'll be drawing anywhere near 200mA with this thing?  If you mean more that, the regulator is rated for that, that's fine -- switching regulators often start in the 100s mA range, there aren't many really tiny ones and extra capacity is fine; but require seems incongruous?

Sorry, I know that it doesn't draw that much current. What I really meant to say is that if that regulator would provide enough output current for my application, and it seems like it does. Thank you for your help.

@TheButterMineCutter From this you can see that $200:\text{mA}$ of current is off-chart. So yeah. Probably wrong IC. Even your second IC shows this. Which doesn't show $5:\text{V}$ input and doesn't reach your end-point. The IC does say switching currents of $1:\text{A}$ or more. The issue is that your duty cycle and peak input current are hitting the limits of this IC. Probably should look further. It's too close to the edge case.

You probably also want to show your layout as well since that will have an impact on performance, especially if you're close to the limit on current or duty cycle.

For 5 volt in, 12 volt out the duty cycle is 1 - Vin/Vout or 58%.  Since your output power is 200 ma @ 12 volts, (2.4 W) the average input current must be at least 480 mA.  Since you are only on 58% of the time, the average input current during the "on time must be 480 mA / 0.58 or 830 mA.
You can see that the peak current will always be higher than the average from the figure from the data sheet below.  The worst case is a peak current of 2 x average current.

The peak current can be calculated from this formula, also from the data sheet:

The MIC2288 has a switch current limit of 1.2 amperes, so it would theoretically just be capable of running a 200 mA instantaneous peak load, as long as it is not continuous.  If you try it, I would use a soft start circuit to keep it out of current limit during start-up.  But I wouldn't drop the SOT version into your existing circuit if your load is 200mA continuous.  Its efficiency will be near 80% at this load, meaning that for a 2.4W output, you must supply 3W.  The 0.6 watt inefficiency will be dissipated as heat in the device, and the data sheet lists its thermal resistance as 256 degrees C/Watt.  This calculates out to a 153-degree rise at 0.6 watts, meaning that at a 25-degree ambient temperature, the chip would theoretically reach 178 degrees if all of the efficiency losses were in the chip (some efficiency losses occur in the external  diode, so it will be less than this).  It has an overtemperature shutdown that occurs at about 150 degrees, so you will always be close to overheating and shut-down.  At 150 mA continuous, the efficiency will be a little better and the losses will be lower.  The chip will run hot but should operate (with a good layout) if you can keep the load here.
Good luck!
